# Convention for capitalising the first letter of a Ruby on Rails file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some standard Ruby on Rails files have the first letter capitalised, e.g. Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, and Guardfile. Is there a convention in regard to this, or can I do this for any file I consider it important?

Comment: Those files are named in imitation of `Makefile`, and this makes them sort higher than the miscellaneous project files. In general, it is not a good idea to name random files with capitals, but if you need them to be sorted near the top of the directory, there's nothing really that is stopping you. Similarly, it has been a long-standing convention to name important *text* files in all caps (as in, those that are a must-read): `INSTALL`, `LICENCE`, `HOWTO` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalized files are not Rails application source files, they are files required by some tools. for example, `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are for `bundler`, and `Guardfile` is for `guard`. None of these tools is shipped with Rails, and all of them can be used without Rails.

You have to stick to Rails conventions, because Rails conventions are not only conventions, they have some performance concerns.

For example, Rails forces you to put your model `MyModel` in the file `app/models/my_model.rb`. Rails will not load this file until this class is used. Rails assume that the class `MyModel` is defined in a file named `my_model.rb`, and is located in one of some special directories called `autoload_paths`, so Rails searches these directories for this specific file and loads it. If no such file, or there's no class `MyModel` defined in that file, then an error will be raised. Using this lazy loading mechanism, Rails can keep those never used (perhaps legacy) classes from being loaded into memory.